# sql pivot function with a defined variable in the IN statement

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, oracle-sqldeveloper

Can anyone tell me how I can make this work?  I either get "ORA-56901: non-constant expression is not allowed for pivot|unpivot values" or I get "ORA-00917: missing comma" depending on whether I put &mb1 in quotes or not in the IN statement.  Thank you!

```
define mb1= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM'),-1);

select *
from
( select COLLECTOR
         ,Month
         ,low_activity_days
  from   dwh_prod.low_activity_days_collect_t) src
pivot
(
  sum(low_activity_days)
  for month in ('&mb1')
) piv;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set your substitution to a fixed value instead, so it isn't trying to to a calculation inside the pivot clause. As you're working with dates you can generate a date literal:

```
set termout off
column x_mb1 new_value mb1
select 'date ''' || TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM'),-1),
  'YYYY-MM-DD') || '''' as x_mb1
from dual;
set termout on

select * from (
  select COLLECTOR ,Month ,low_activity_days
  from dwh_prod.low_activity_days_collect_t
) src
pivot ( sum(low_activity_days) for month in (&mb1) ) piv;
```

The first query - with the output hidden by `termout` generates a string:

```
select 'date ''' || TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM'),-1),
  'YYYY-MM-DD') || '''' as x_mb1
from dual;

X_MB1            
-----------------
date '2017-03-01'
```

The [`column ... new_value` command](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve013.htm) then sets `&mb` to that. The substitution in your really query then becomes:

```
select * from (
  select COLLECTOR ,Month ,low_activity_days
  from dwh_prod.low_activity_days_collect_t
) src
pivot ( sum(low_activity_days) for month in (date '2017-03-01') ) piv
```

The problem with your original code is that you're ending up with a reference to `sysdate` inside the substituted pivot clause, which throws the ORA-56901 exception (since `sysdate` isn't constant). You can use any fixed value in the pivot, so you *could* do:

```
define mb1=''01-APR-17''
... for month in (&mb1) ) piv;
```

with the qoutes around the string as part of the definition, or

```
define mb1='01-APR-17'
... for month in ('&mb1') ) piv;
```

without, or other variations. But because those end up as string you're relying on implicit date conversion, and relying on your NLS settings; with the date literal I'm generating that isn't an issue. If you really wanted to use that date format you could still do:

```
define mb1='01-APR-17'
... for month in (to_date('&mb1', 'DD-MON-RR')) ) piv;
```

or select the date in that specific format with the `new_values` method:

```
column x_mb1 new_value mb1
select to_char(add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), -1), 'DD-MON-RR') as x_mb1 from dual;
... for month in (to_date('&mb1', 'DD-MON-RR')) ) piv;
```

Using the date literal format still seems simpler to me though.

---

I'm not sure why pivoting a single value is particularly useful though. Maybe your real query is doing more, but simple aggregation and a filter look more appropriate here:

```
select collector, sum(low_activity_days)
from low_activity_days_collect_t
where month = add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), -1)
group by collector;
```

---

If you want a rolling 12-month summary you don't need to build the pivot quite that dynamically; you can generate a month-offset number based on the current date, which will give you a fixed range of numeric values you can pivot on (rather than dates), something like:

```
select * from (
  select collector, low_activity_days,
    months_between(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), month) as month_offset
  from low_activity_days_collect_t
  where month >= add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), -13)
  and month < trunc(sysdate, 'MM')
) src
pivot (sum(low_activity_days) as months_ago
  for month_offset in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12));
```

which will give columns `collector`, `1_months_ago`, `2_months_ago` etc.

What you can't easily do is make the column headings represent the actual month (e.g. 2017-04, 2017-03, ...), but you don't seem to have been trying to do that anyway; and unless you alias the pivoted column terms the ones generated in this example have to be treated as quoted identifiers (because they start with numbers).

If you do want month headers you could generate those with some more substitution variable shenanigans, with something like this before the query:

```
set termout off
column x_m1 new_value m1
column x_m2 new_value m2
...
column x_m12 new_value m12
select to_char(add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), -1), 'YYYY-MM') as x_m1,
  to_char(add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), -2), 'YYYY-MM') as x_m2,
  ...
  to_char(add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), -12), 'YYYY-MM') as x_m12
from dual;
column 1_months_ago heading &m1
column 2_months_ago heading &m2
...
column 12_months_ago heading &m12
set termout on
```

You might find it easier to use a proper reporting tool to query and format/display the results for you though.

Comment: Thank you Alex.  You are right.  I have to do this for the last twelve months, but I need it to be a rolling twelve months.  I was just using one month to try to get it working.

Comment: I tried your code, including several variations of it and I keep getting the error: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 22 Column: 53

Comment: What are the datatypes of the columns in your table?

Comment: The Month column is in the format dd-Mon-yy.  The rest are COLLECTOR VARCHAR2(133 BYTE)
COLL_GROUP VARCHAR2(22 BYTE)
COLL_TYPE VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)
DAY VARCHAR2(9 BYTE)
LOW_ACTIVITY_DAYS NUMBER
MONTH DATE
SUB_GROUP VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)

Comment: I'm not sure how you're seeing that error then, I've tried it some dummy data with those data types and didn't see any issues. but then I don't know what line 22 character 53 points to in your script, so maybe it's from elsewhere?

Comment: OK, so this is weird:  I tried your exact code again (I added a right parenthesis right before the "piv;") and now it prompts me for the &mb1 variable.  At the prompt, if I set &mb1= '01-APR-17', it works like a charm!  All I'm doing is highlighting everything you wrote and doing CTRL+Enter

Comment: I just tried    define mb1='''01-APR-17''';   then did the pivot syntax and it worked.  No joke.  I really don't get it.  But, whatever...

Comment: The pivot code is the same as mine, I had the same parentheses. You've changed the first query, to get the `x_mb1` value, though. Why? You could make your query select get `TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM'),-1), '"''"DD-MON-YY"''"')` to force single quotes around it; but then you're relying on implicit conversion in the pivot. The date literal I used avoided that.

Comment: @Mark - yes, `define mb1=''01-APR-17''` will work, but then you're doing implicit conversion inside the pivot, which isn't a good idea. (See previous comment for how to get that in the same format at runtime instead of hard-coding it). That's why I used a date literal. Also, I edited my answer to show a different way to get a rolling 12-month window.

Comment: @Mark - I've added some examples closer to what you tried to my answer too. Hopefully that makes what you're seeing a bit clearer.

Comment: Two things:  1) Supposing I was trying to make the dates the column headers though?  2) Here's what I don't get (and forgive me for being ignorant) but why does it prompt me for &mb1 when I am clearly defining it in the column statement?

Comment: (1) is probably out of scope for this question. For (2), not sure unless you're running it as a statement instead of a query, and even then it remembers the previous value in 4.2.0; maybe you're on an earlier version of SQL Developer that behaves slightly differently? Or it isn't running the query that generates `x_mb1` for some reason, or you ran *that* as a statement. What you showed earlier looked OK as far as I can remember, if all run as a script.